# Сайт на ajax

Tags: ajax

Нужно сделать изменение части страницы по клику на пункт меню, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать =)
В ajax пока ничего не смыслю, потому и спрашиваю)

Comment: Так почитайте про AJAX, это не сложно.

Answer (score 1):

При клике на пункт меню должна запускаться js функция, которая отправляет запрос на сервер и принимает от сервера ответ. Затем, в случае успешного выполнения запроса эта функция будет, например, менять текст на странице, а в случае получения от сервера сообщения об ошибке - выводить ошибку. Как-то так.

Comment: А код-то как выглядит? :D
Для меня js тоже темный лес)

Comment: Ну, например:

function callServer() {
  // Получить city и state из web-формы
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").value;

  if ((city == null) || (city == "")) return;
  if ((state == null) || (state == "")) return;

  // URL скрипта на сервере
  var url = "/scripts/getZipCode.php?city=" + escape(city) + "&state=" + escape(state);

  // Открыть соединение
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);

  // Установить функцию для сервера после его ответа
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;

  // Передать запрос
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

Comment: Если решили написать сайт на Ajax, то в начале изучите JavaScritp и то, что планируете использовать на серверной стороне - PHP, C#, CGI или ещё чего...